# Add an external javascript function on a button in admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, external

I have a little problem to add an external javascript function in a `<select>`.

I've got a file form.php in /app/code/local/{my_namespace}/{my_module}/Block/Adminhtml/{my_entity}/edit/tab/form.php

I've got another file in js/{my_module}/verifForm.js

In my form.php, there is one select field where I put a : 'onchange' => 'myfunction()'

And myfunction() appear in verifForm.js
At the moment, it's just an alert('hello') in it, just to try.

But it doesn't work, when I change the select, my console says : Uncaught ReferenceError: myfunction is not defined

So there is my question, how can I call this external function with my onchange ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use your module layout xml, local.xml or other layout to add your custom javascript to the page header

eg

```
<yourpackage_yourmodule_yourcontroller_action translate="label" module="yourpackage_yourmodule">       
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs">
            <script>{my_module}/verifForm.js</script>
        </action>
    </reference>
</yourpackage_yourmodule_yourcontroller_action>
```

See [Layout for Magento module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324598/layout-for-magento-module)